# GraphQL - DateTime not showing time in local timezone value

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql

I'm working on a ToDo list App in GrapQL, Node and PostgreSQL.

As my entity, I have a Card which contains those fields for DateTime:
created_at and updated_at.

I manage to create a scalar Date to manage the DateTime format but the time is in the format:

```
"created_at": "2019-08-24T23:11:02.376Z",
"updated_at": "2019-09-01T15:04:12.627Z"
```

I would like to have the format showing the actual time of the time zone I'm. The above time is `Z` and it is 2h behind my time.

I did as following for my scalar Date:

```
import { GraphQLScalarType, GraphQLError } from 'graphql';
import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';
import { isISO8601 } from 'validator';

export default new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'Date',
    description: 'Date type',
    parseValue(value): Date {
        if (isISO8601(value))
            // value comes from the client
            return new Date(value); // sent to resolvers
        throw new Error('DateTime cannot represent an invalid ISO-8601 Date string');
    },
    serialize(value): Promise<string> {
        if (isISO8601(value))
            // value comes from resolvers
            return value.toISOString(); // sent to the client
        throw new Error('DateTime cannot represent an invalid ISO-8601 Date string');
    },
    parseLiteral(ast): Date {
        // ast comes from parsing the query
        // this is where you can validate and transform
        if (ast.kind !== Kind.STRING) {
            throw new GraphQLError(`Query error: Can only parse dates strings, got a: ${ast.kind}`, [ast]);
        }
        if (isNaN(Date.parse(ast.value))) {
            throw new GraphQLError(`Query error: not a valid date`, [ast]);
        }

        if (isISO8601(ast.value)) return new Date(ast.value);

        throw new Error('DateTime cannot represent an invalid ISO-8601 Date string');
    },
});
```

My entity for the Card:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, CreateDateColumn, UpdateDateColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity('cards')
export class Card {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @CreateDateColumn()
    created_at: Date;

    @UpdateDateColumn()
    updated_at: Date;

    @Column('text')
    title: string;

    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
    })
    description: string;

    @Column('boolean', {
        default: 'false',
    })
    done: boolean;
}
```

The type for the card:

```
export const Card = `
    scalar Date

    type Card {
        id          : String
        title       : String
        description : String
        done        : Boolean
        created_at  : Date
        updated_at  : Date
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

In client side you can use [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to format your returned date,

and you can use moment framework in back-end As well,

but you need to set your local time zone :

```
moment(yourDate).local("your-local");
```

example :

```
moment("2019-08-24T23:11:02.376Z").local("ar-IQ");
```

Comment: That good I can use that solution when I will build the client-side. At the moment I'm building an API and will need to know if I can on the backend side make the change or understand why better not and keep it only on the client side in the future.

Comment: i have updated my answer, and i think it's better to do that in client side  , I hope that will help you

Comment: Could you show me please an example using my code above how to use the moment to get that right?

Comment: I’m really sorry I am not familiar with GraphQL api, but I recommend converting date in client side because you don’t know from which time zone the client request the api

Answer (score 0):

I can give an example how to convert the timestamp in SQL: As far as I understand `Z` is the same as `UTC`.

So in order to get the date and time in "your" timezone you can `select` it with the following syntax:

```
# Example: America/Campo_Grande
select created_at at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'America/Campo_Grande' from cards;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT

I do not know how this can be done in this specific GraphQL environment.